# How do I conditionally return a prediction of the next record's auto_increment value?

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do can be accomplished.    I'm using MySQL 5.7.9.  I want my query to return for a field the value for the record or, if it's null, one more than the maximum value of that field for all records, including the records not being returned.  As I read the definition of the MAX() function, I don't think it's what I need.

For example, if I have a table personnel

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith |
| 2 | John Adams |
| 3 | Samuel Adams |

which can be created and populated thus:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
workorder int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
entered_by int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
reviewed_by int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (workorder),
FOREIGN KEY (entered_by) REFERENCES personnel(id),
FOREIGN KEY (reviewed_by) REFERENCES personnel(id)
);
ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
INSERT INTO personnel(name) VALUES('John Smith');
INSERT INTO personnel(name) VALUES('John Adams');
INSERT INTO personnel(name) VALUES('Samuel Adams');
```

and a table reports:

| id | personnel |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

which can be created and populated thus:

```
CREATE TABLE reports(
id int(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
personnel int(10) unsigned,
FOREIGN KEY (personnel) REFERENCES personnel(id)
);
INSERT INTO reports (personnel) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO reports (personnel) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO reports (personnel) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO reports (personnel) VALUES (3);
```

and I'm looking to find the latest report id for a personnel, or if there is none, a prediction of what it will be if it is immediately added (which, of course will be one more than the max value in the id field).

Comment: What you need to do is publish sample data and expected outcome (as text)

Comment: If `GO` is an auto_incremented column, how come it's NULL and should it be defined as `not null`?

Answer (score 0):

If your `MySQL` supports window function you can use:

```
SELECT a, case when go is null then 1 + lag(go) OVER (ORDER BY a)  else go end as go
FROM test_tbl;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> a go
> a 1
> b 2
> c 3
> d 4
> ```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e7f54d06caa83be71bad3b2f364ece5

Answer (score 0):

from this you can find values for null column

```
SELECT case when `go` is null then (SELECT max(`go`)+1 from `test`) else `go` end as `go` FROM `test`
```

output

```
go
1
2
3
4
```

and then by using max on above query you will get maximum value of resultant data

```
select max(`go`) from (SELECT case when `go` is null then (SELECT max(`go`)+1 from `test`) else `go` end as `go` FROM `test`) as tbl1
```